# Server Side Rendering in React not being invoked

Tags: html, reactjs, server-side-rendering, isomorphic

I'm obviously missing something here. I have a simple React class that I want to convert to using Server Side Rendering but I can't get the initial component to render on the server.

I've altered my initial App class to use renderToString

```
const App = ()=> {    
  var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<div>
         <div className="jumbotron text-center">
           <h1>Welcome!</h1>
         </div>
         <div className="container">
           <MyComponent />
         </div>
       </div>);
   return html;
}

export default App;
```

I've updated the index.js file to use hydrate:

```
ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I don't, however, get MyComponent rendered in the browser. What I get is the HTML for MyComponent displayed in the browser page. If, in the browser, I look at the page source, I can see that the component's HTML isn't being downloaded with the page (the root  element used in hydrate is empty). When I use the Developer's Tools elements tab, I can see all of my component's HTML has been inserted into the root  element inside a quoted string (which is why it's displayed in the browser page).

I'm assuming that's what's happening is that my component is *not* being rendered on the server but is still being invoked from the browser. The result is that my renderToString is returning a string to the client of all of my component's HTML which hydrate dutifully inserts into my root  element.

What am I missing here? I created the application with npx create-react-app and am using version 16.8.0.

Comment: Do you have a server setup to do so? Post a version of your servercode too?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by servercode? Are there specific configuration files, for example, that you're looking for?

If it's any help: This is a vanilla React application running in Visual Studio Code using the development server that comes with the npx package.

Comment: You need to create a server to have server-side rendering. Look at this -> https://flaviocopes.com/react-server-side-rendering/. You need to have a server listening out for a request the throws React when called upon.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of thing that I'm missing. And you're saying that the development server set up with npx isn't set up that way by default and/or additional code is required to integrate with that server.

Comment: Nope. You need to create your own server or you could use `Nextjs` for server side rendering in React.